# Replacing null values by zero before subtracting the row from the previous row in the same group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question concerning the subtraction and null values. Here is my code which is computing the subtraction between the value (Column Value in the sub-query) in the current row and in the previous one (previous DateTime) in each group separately:

```
WITH CTE (DateTime, Compteur, Valeur) AS 
(
SELECT DateTime, Compteur, CASE WHEN Valeur<0 OR Valeur IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Valeur END AS Valeur
FROM
(
    SELECT  DateTime, TagName AS Compteur
    ,       Value - LAG(Value, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName ORDER BY DateTime) AS Valeur
    FROM History 
    WHERE  TagName IN ('A','B')
    AND DateTime >='2018-12-31 23:59:00'
    AND wwRetrievalMode='Delta'
)t
WHERE t.DateTime >='2018-12-31 23:59:59'
)
SELECT DateTime, Compteur, Valeur INTO #tempcounters from CTE
```

But if the value in the previous row is NULL then the subtraction gives a NULL. To avoid this issue I would like to replace all the NULL values with the previous non-NULL values in the same group before subtracting. Here is the example:

```
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|     DateTime        |     Compteur     |      Valeur
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------
|  15.04.2019 16:51:30|         A        |       10
|---------------------|------------------|----------------- 
|  15.04.2019 16:52:42|         A        |       NULL
|---------------------|------------------|----------------- 
|  15.04.2019 16:53:14|         A        |       NULL
|---------------------|------------------|----------------- 
|  15.04.2019 17:52:14|         A        |       15
|---------------------|------------------|----------------- 
|  15.04.2019 16:51:30|         B        |       6
|---------------------|------------------|----------------- 
|  15.04.2019 16:52:42|         B        |       9
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------
|  15.04.2019 16:53:14|         B        |       NULL
|---------------------|------------------|----------------- 
|  15.04.2019 17:52:14|         B        |       15
|---------------------|------------------|----------------
```

The new table should look like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|     DateTime        |     Compteur     |      Valeur
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------
|  15.04.2019 16:51:30|         A        |       NULL
|---------------------|------------------|----------------- 
|  15.04.2019 16:52:42|         A        |       0
|---------------------|------------------|----------------- 
|  15.04.2019 16:53:14|         A        |       0
|---------------------|------------------|----------------- 
|  15.04.2019 17:52:14|         A        |       5
|---------------------|------------------|----------------- 
|  15.04.2019 16:51:30|         B        |       NULL
|---------------------|------------------|----------------- 
|  15.04.2019 16:52:42|         B        |       3
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------
|  15.04.2019 16:53:14|         B        |       0
|---------------------|------------------|----------------- 
|  15.04.2019 17:52:14|         B        |       6
|---------------------|------------------|----------------
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

use coalesce

```
WITH CTE (DateTime, Compteur, Valeur) AS 


(
SELECT DateTime, Compteur, CASE WHEN Valeur<0 OR Valeur IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Valeur END AS Valeur
FROM
(
    SELECT  DateTime, TagName AS Compteur
    ,       Value - coalesce( LAG(Value, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName ORDER BY DateTime),0) AS Valeur
    FROM History 
    WHERE  TagName IN ('A','B')
    AND DateTime >='2018-12-31 23:59:00'
    AND wwRetrievalMode='Delta'
)t
WHERE t.DateTime >='2018-12-31 23:59:59'
)
SELECT DateTime, Compteur, Valeur INTO #tempcounters from CTE
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But in this case the fourth row in the group A would be 0 instead of 5. I would like to replace NULL value by 10 and than calculate the difference between 15 and 10.

Comment: @sgokce if you want to replace null value by 10 then used 10 inplace 0 inside coalesce

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding but 10 is not a constant but it was the previous non-null value in the column regarding the DateTime. I hope it is clearer now!

Comment: @sgokce then try to use recursive query